# Node.js - "Rebind" UDP socket server to a new port

Tags: node.js, sockets, udp, port

Which is the most efficient way to change a UDP server's listening port on runtime on Node.js?

I have a default port `41234` for my web app but I want the end-user to be able to change this through a settings textbox, which would call the `updatePort()`.

Using the following code the new (neither the old) port isn't actually listening for datagrams, as I cant receive anything.

```
var SRV_PORT = 41234;
var server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

server.on("error", function (err) {
  print("server error:\n" + err.stack);
  server.close();
});

server.on("message", function (msg, rinfo) {
  //code for incoming datagram analysis here
});

server.on("listening", function () {
  var address = server.address();
  print("server listening " + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

//start the UDP server with the default SRV_PORT
server.bind(SRV_PORT);

function updatePort(newPort) {
  server.close();
  server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
  server.bind(newPort);
}
```

Comment: Well, the reason you wouldn't get any messages after updating the port is because you've assigned a new socket instance to `server` and do not have any event handlers attached anymore.

Comment: Just copied the listening and message event handlers into updatePort() and you seem to be right. I do receive datagrams on the the new port. So I need to figure out how to set the code now..

Comment: The reason for this error is expressed in your title. You wanted to rebind a socket. You can't rebind a socket. You have to create a new one. You did that, but you didn't carry the consequences through.

Comment: Ye, I thought that the original event handlers would do (I'm not sure yet why there are not, but anyway). This works.

Comment: @mscdex, you can repost your comment as an answer to accept it and grant you the credits. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you wouldn't get any messages after updating the port is because you've assigned a new socket instance to server and do not have any event handlers attached anymore.